# How to change focus on textbox dynamically?

Tags: javascript, textbox, focus

I'm working on a script that interacts with an html page.

The html page has **two text boxes, and a submit button**.

Each time you press the send button the focus on the textbox moves from the first to the second and so on.

Until now I couldn't `onFocus` to interact with the code. Who can help me figure out how to fix it?

I found this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp

This is my html code:

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="c1"><br>
<input type="text" id="c2"><br>
<input type="button" id="enter" onClick="focus();">

<script>
function focus()
{

}
<script>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, with an empty function, no wonder you can't get anything to work... try something then come back. oh and as a piece of advice, try avoiding inline javascript, and finding better sources of information than w3schools which is not always right/accurate, and sometimes very false.

Comment: You should btw always use onclick (lowercase) in favor of onClick! Further <br> should be changed to <br /> ;)

Comment: the function is empty because I would like your advice to the solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the focus() method for the element you want to be focused:

```
function focus()
{
    document.activeElement.nextSibling.focus();
}
```

that should move the focus to the next dom element each time you click the button.

Edit:

You could write something like this:

```
function focus()
{
    if (document.activeElement.getAttribute('id') == 'c1'){
        document.getElementById('c2').focus();
    }else {
        document.getElementById('c1').focus();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I focus the textbox every time you press the button? 
Should I do a for loop?

Comment: I added a solution for switching between both fields.

Comment: yeah but don't catch the pression of the button

Comment: it migth be, that you need to insert a onfocus() function within both input fields to save the active input field in a variable. based on this vairable you can change the focus to the next field. You could also save the input field next to focus. This allows you to get along without the if/else conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all u want to do is check to see if the form has been filled in? If not it focuses on a particular field which has not been filled in?